# for-loop iteration only appends the first - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, txt, keyerror

You see I want to create a sorted array from all DW values, but it only works for the first 1x100 or if I try other methods it either raises a KeyError: 1, invalid index to scalar variable...

I have searched the internet endlessly and tried many combinations to get y such that it works.

the value d, epsilon_hat and betas are all great, If I just do it for `y = y[i]` (outside of a loop) yet whenever I try to do it like this it does only give errors...

Anyone knows how I can write something like `y = y[i]` such that all 10000 columns get put in the array `d_test_hats`, and not just one?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely the `y = y[i]` line.
Don't reassign your `y` in the loop. I'm not sure what your `y` is, I assume it's a multidimensional array. Each time you iterate through your loop you remove one dimension from `y`.

Short explanation where your code goes wrong:

```
y = [1,2,3]
for i in range(3):
    y = y[i]
    print(y)
```

will have the output:

```
1
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

Your 'KeyError' say's pretty much the same thing - I guess you have a numpy scalar in hand and therefore your message is different - but the error is the same - you cannot use `[]` on a number (aka scalar).

What happens here:

- First Iteration: `y=[1,2,3]; i=0`
- `y` is assigned: `y=y[i] <=> y=[1,2,3][0]`
- print: `print(y) <=> print(1)`
- Second Iteration: `y=1; i=1`
- `y` is assigned: `y=y[i] <=> y=1[1] <== TypeError: 'int' is not subscriptable`

TL;DR:

Remove the `y = y[i]` line and

change `epsilon_hat = y - X.dot(betas)` to `epsilon_hat = y[i] - X.dot(betas)`

or write `y_layer = y[i]` and use `y_layer` in the loop.

Comment: yes, thank you! y is 10000 1(columns)x100(rows) which represent observations in a parametric time series model. I intend to test for autocorrelation in the regression residuals. so, a Durbin-Watson statistic equaling 2 would mean no correlation (correlation=rho=0, in d=2(1-p)). Yet now that I've used your lifesaving answer, I get another  error... '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' for the d_test_hats.sort()...

Comment: Oh boy, not every python programmer is a data-scientist... I've no idea what you're talking about haha
It seems your `value_d` is of type `dict` for some reason. From looking at the code I cannot really figure out why though, I'd need more debug information. Can you give me the outputs of `print(f"{type(numerator_d_hat)=} {type(denominator_d_hat)=} {type(value_d)=}")` at the end of the inner loop please.

Comment: By the way I think your `epsilon_hat = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, n)` should probably be outside the inner loop as you create a new distribution for each iteration of the inner loop instead of iterating through one distribution.

By the way: Please mark my answer as accepted so I get the reputation points.

Comment: I get this when trying to upvote: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: I see why its giving the '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' for the d_test_hats.sort(). As when the epsilon_hat = epsilon_hat.iloc[:,0] is run 100 times, the correct column becomes epsilon_hat.iloc[:,1], and does this well, 10000 times. so only the first 100 are correct. Any way to change my 'variable' in this epsilon_hat = epsilon_hat.iloc[:,i] S.T. i goes i+1 for every 100 times it has been run ?

Comment: regarding the random.normal thing, i used a np.random.seed(123) such that it uses the same simulation each time.

Comment: @GuusBouwens I'm confused by your previous comments...
A potential source of many errors is that you name your loop variable `i` in the outer and in the inner loop. I'd recommend calling the inner loop variable `j` (aka - inner loop is: `for j in range(1, n)` also note that `range(x,y)` is inclusive `x` and exclusive `y` (last element of the range will be `y-1`) - regarding your `random.normal` thing, you set the seed only at the start of your function, you'll still have different values for `epsilon_hat` in each iteration of the inner function (and you're keeping the cpu busy for no reason)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73901468/python-change-variable-inside-a-for-loop-after-each-n-times-run As my problem has become different and my code works I've made another post concerning the problem with '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' for the d_test_hats.sort(). Also my code is more up to date there!