# Python - change variable inside a for-loop after each n times run?

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop, iteration, nan

I see why its giving the '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' for the sorted(d_test_hats). As when the epsilon_hat = epsilon_hat.iloc[:,0] is run 100 times, the correct column becomes epsilon_hat.iloc[:,1], and does this well, 10000/100=100 times. so only the first 100 are correct. As all the other 99 columns are just nan. Any way to change my 'variable' in this epsilon_hat = epsilon_hat.iloc[:,i] S.T. 0 goes 0+1 for every 100 (untill 100) times it has been run?

Comment: `if j % n == 0:` will be true every n iterations.

Comment: `epsilon_hat = epsilon_hat.iloc[:, i]` - `i` will only increase every `n-1` iterations of the inner loop.

Comment: unfortunately, this still makes `epsilon_hat = epsilon_hat.iloc[:,j-1] - j` go immediately to the next column. Hence this only the first iterations yields a non-nan value. (j-1 as i need to start at `epsilon_hat = epsilon_hat.iloc[:,0]`, and remain there for 100 iterations.

Comment: Thank you! But, @Barmar I'm sorry when I apply this it does not work for me, as                     
            `epsilon_hat = y_layer - X.dot(betas)
            print(epsilon_hat)
            if j % n == 0:
                epsilon_hat = epsilon_hat.iloc[:,j-1]
            print(epsilon_hat)`                                                                                                
            will keep the `epsilon_hat = y_layer - X.dot(betas)` it's value. How should I work this `if j % n == 0:` into my code.

Comment: "I see why its giving the '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict' for the sorted(d_test_hats)." - **What is "it"**? What are you referring to?